# Rails 3/delayed_job - Wanted: Basic example of delayed mail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I've been trying to figure out how to send delayed mail using delayed_job with rails 3. I've tried pretty much every combination of feasible possibilities I can think of - I can get the mail to run in the background, I just can't get it to delay the sending to a future time. The delayed_jobs table in the db clears the tasks, the log says 'sent', the delayed_job task processor picks up the task & says sent without failure...but the mail is either:

- sent immediately, or
- simply doesn't arrive

if I try to send in the future.

If anyone could offer a bare-bones example of a rails 3 delayed_job that sends mail in the future, I'd be really appreciative. I'm sure lotsa folks do this so I suspect I'm missing something obvious. One (of countless) combinations I've tried below:

delayed_job: 2.1.2
rails: 3.0.3
actionmailer: 3.0.3

Controller:

```
class TestmailerController < ApplicationController
  def index
    Testmailer.delay.test_mail
  end

end
```

Mailer:

```
class Testmailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def test_mail
    mail(:to => '(myemailaddress@removedforprivacy.com', :from => '(removedforprivacy)@gmail.com', :subject => 'Testing Delayed Job', :content_type => 'text/plain').deliver
  end
  handle_asynchronously :test_mail, :run_at => Proc.new { 2.minutes.from_now }


end
```

relevant mail part of config/environments/development.rb:

```
  # Don't care if the mailer can't send
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }

  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port => 587,
    :domain => "gmail.com",
    :user_name => "(removedforprivacy)",
    :password => "(removedforprivacy)",
    :authentication => "plain",
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

Job command:

```
rake jobs:work
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I agree with andrea - I was having this exact problem, and after switching my local development database from sqlite to mysql, I can run code like

```
Emailer.delay({:run_at => 5.minutes.from_now}).welcome(@user)
```

and it sends the email 5 minutes later.  Note that you might need a bigger delay than five minutes (in case of time zone weirdness) to be sure it is working.

Comment: do you know how to accomplish this without the delay method.  I want to use the handle_async... method.  I like being able to make a method delayed in all called places, rather than changing all callers.

Answer (score 1):

Both using the `.delay` method and setting `handle_asynchronously :test_mail` is redundant. Try removing the `.delay` method from your code. use simply

```
Testmailer.test_mail   # without .deliver due to a delayed_job issue
```

However, I ran some test on your configuration and when using **sqlite**, `run_at` is simply ignored (do not know why), but when using **mysql2** everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I found in Rails 3 with mongoid that removing the handle_asynchronously line gets it to work. I was having all kinds of problems, and it appeared that delayed_job wasn't recognizing any objects within my Emailer class. Removing handle_asynchronously fixed it.